# Mobile Hamburger Menu Location

Tags: mobile, menu, hamburger, location

With the advent of larger mobile devices (e.g. Samsung Galaxy Note and iPhone 6 Plus), reaching toward specific actions on a website requires additional effort.

[image: Ease of thumb reach map]

Can anyone reference a mobile web precedent (*not an app*) for positioning the hamburger menu in the lower part of the screen? The example we have been referencing is Google Maps: it provides a type of menu at the bottom of the page.

[image: Google Maps on Android]

Comment: asking for examples of other sites isn't a good SE question. Instead, perhaps you could ask if there is any precedent for hamburger menus not being located at the top. FYI, the menu in the lower right isn't really a hamburger menu. It's an 'etc' type of icon for a toolbar. Luke Wroblewski has named that a 'kebab menu': https://twitter.com/lukew/status/590911111358242816

Comment: I would also ask how often a user needs to access your app's menu with one hand. If it's frequently, I'd argue that perhaps a hamburger menu is the wrong navigation model to use in the first place.

Comment: Please consider how often your users will take different actions. For example, if they will "searching" or want to "view their current location" for most of the time on your site, then appropriate buttons ought to be more easy to press (middle/bottom of the screen, fab). Actions/screens with less priority can be placed for ex. under hamburger menu.

Answer (score 1):

I'd consider this as well, and it seems to be an element that is getting a closer look. [**Material Design**](http://www.google.com/design/spec/material-design/introduction.html) introduces the floating button concept as Android's default, so expect to see more and more actions (eg expand menu) on bottom or safe sides of larger devices.

Now, I'll play devil advocate's and recommend you to check the [Affordances](https://www.interaction-design.org/encyclopedia/affordances.html) article by Mads Soegaard that takes both Norman's and Gibson's definitions. Here you'll understand why this is still a difficult move, because most users expects to see that element on top.

With all this being said, it's possible to create an alternative that considers all scenarios: for example, you could use a *floating action button* and target big mobile screens so the floating action shows on bottom or maybe middle of screen, then use a [*bottom sheet*](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/bottom-sheets.html) to display your menu. And on regular mobile screens, keep the menu on top and use the bottom sheet or just a regular dropdown menu.

However, keep in mind that I'm talking about **MENU**. Whether you use the hamburger icon or something else goes on you and your testing of the element